# dynamic SQL query giving type error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, dynamic

I am trying to write a simple SP by building dynamic queries and storing in a variable and executing the variable.

I currently get the following error:

> Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 16
>   Operand type clash: datetime2 is incompatible with float

For the following code:

```
DECLARE 
@table_Num
@1 varchar(100) = 'boo',
@2 int =2,
@3 varchar(100) ='default',
@4 varchar(50) = NULL,
@5 int =NULL,
@6 float =12,
@7 datetime2(0) ='1970-01-01 00:00:00',
@8 datetime2(0)='1970-01-01 00:00:00',
@9 varchar(50)='',
@10 varchar(50)=NULL,
@11 decimal(18,0)=0000000000000,
@12 int =999999

DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @SQLString = 'INSERT INTO abc_'+@table_Num+'(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10, col11, col12) 
VALUES ('+@1+',2,'+@3+','+@4+','+@5+','+@6+','+@7+','+@8+','+@9+','+@10+','+@11+','+@12+')'

EXEC (@SQLString)
```

As far as I can see the variables are same type as table col types. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you include the definition of `table_1` as well please?

Comment: This is the absolute worst possible way to build a dynamic SQL string. Can you explain why it needs to be dynamic SQL in the first place?

Comment: @AaronBertrand great point. I just took it for granted that there was even a reason for this to be dynamic SQL.

Comment: I thought it had to be dynamic sql as i neeed the params to be in the insert statment

Comment: @Fearghal you can call the params/variables directly in your insert statement. No need to use dynamic SQL unless you are building a different insert statement each time (like leaving out certain params, etc.)

Comment: ok i may have missed somehting, standby, il check it out ina few hours.... thanks for you're help.

Comment: ok so i looked at your suggestions and knew i was missing somehting - my example showed a static table name, i need to be able to state the tablename dynamically, thats why i was going down route of dynamic select string

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing it has something to do with your use of quotation marks, but it's quite hard to follow. I'd recommend using `EXEC sp_executesql` and passing your parameters as actual parameters. It's a little easier to do for a statement like this, and much more secure.

*(Edited based on comment from TimLehner)*

```
DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(MAX), @ParamString NVARCHAR(MAX), @TableName sysname;
SET @TableName = N'abc_' + REPLACE(@table_num, '''', ''''''); --Escape apostrophes

IF OBJECT_ID(@TableName) IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
  SET @SQLString = 
    N'INSERT INTO ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) +
    N' (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10, col11, col12)
       VALUES (@1, @2, @3, @4, @5, @6, @7, @8, @9, @10, @11, @12)';
  SET @ParamString = N'@1 varchar(100), @2 int, @3 varchar(100), ... , @12 int)';

  EXEC sp_executesql @SQLString, @ParamString, @1, @2, @3, @4, @5, @6, @7, @8, @9, @10, @11, @12
END
```

[Read about sp_execultesql on MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx).

Comment: +1 [`sp_executesql` is absolutely the way to execute dynamic SQL](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/09/17/bad-habits-to-kick-using-exec-instead-of-sp-executesql.aspx), particularly when most of the parameters can be strongly typed (vs. glomming them together as one big string).

Comment: @AaronBertrand thanks for the edit. You're right, the parens were a mistake.

Comment: guys, i amended my original quiesion - i wanted to state the table name dynamically and this wasnt in example doh! Does this change anything - eg '....table_'+@table_num+'(....

Comment: That will still work very well with sp_executesql. I've updated my answer above; it's only a small change. You'll need to concatenate the table name into the SQL command, but everything else should still be passed as parameters.

Comment: Thanks agaan. I dupliacted this, added a few tweaks to make it work -' at end of last line, declared table_num....getting error: Must declare the scalar variable @1.

Comment: Sorry to ask the obvious question, but you do still have @1 through @12 defined at the top of your stored proc, right? Assuming you do, try adding `PRINT @SQLString` and `PRINT @ParamString` and running, so we can see what's actually being executed.

Comment: @JeffRosenberg I would suggest some safety by doubling apostrophes and checking for existence of the table.

Comment: @TimLehner fair enough, I'll try to edit shortly. In my defense, I wrote the update to my answer on the bus. :-)

Answer (score 3):

To create a correct insert statement dynamically you would have to, at the very least:

1. Cast variables to strings: `cast(@2 as varchar(11))`
2. Double apostrophes in strings: `replace(@1, '''', '''''')`
3. Wrap strings (including dates as strings) in apostrophes: `'''' + replace(@1, '''', '''''') + ''''`
4. Handle nulls, since concatenating a null yields null: `coalesce(cast(@5 as varchar(11)), 'null')`

Doesn't this look *terrible*?

As mentioned by others, this is the worst way to run dynamic SQL, and opens a major security hole called **SQL Injection**.  If this needs to be dynamic, please use [`sp_executesql`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) with typed parameters instead (Thanks, @JeffRosenberg).  However, this simple insert is also a trivial example and shouldn't require dynamic SQL at all (Thanks, @AaronBertrand).  Simply run the command as-is:

```
INSERT INTO table_1 (col1, col2, /* ... */ col12)
VALUES (@1, @2, /* ... */ @12)
```

Comment: Hi guys, sorry i meade a mistake in my example, it prob doesnt make too much diff but heres the diff.... I want to be able to state the tabel name being inserted into dymamically, I have changed the original questions code accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You have a casting problem in your string concatenation. You need to cast your parameters to varchar to build your string.

cast(@7 as varchar(50)).

FWIW, I think that you should rethink how you are building up your query. If possible, avoid using EXEC(). You will run in to all kinds of problems with this solution. You might also get a problem SQL injection. Your insert query could be rewritten if a hacker manages to send int SQL code in e.g. the parameter @1

Comment: Thanks, i tried the varchar approach, think i ran into another issue but il check it out again.